# 百强 specification?

Tags: meaning

[**百强** (MDBG)](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E7%99%BE%E5%BC%BA):

> top 100 (e.g. top 100 towns)

[Adsotrans](http://www.popupchinese.com/tools/adso):

> top one-hundred

[CFDict](http://cfdict.fr/)

> top 100

- Cebu Pacific calls themselves a 百强企业 on their advertisements
- 蓝润集团 calls themselves 百强蓝润 on their advertisements

Fortune Five Hundred translates as 五百强, I can't imagine that Cebu or Lanrun would make the *Fortune 100*.

**What's the scope of 百强?**

Top one hundred -of- *what*?

Comment: Found news title '蓝润集团入榜中国房地产前100强'. So that it is. http://house.baidu.com/sc/scan/0/5986738501256011448/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrow and is not really about Chinese language or culture. I haven't heard any other business affix their name in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

百强 means top 100.  The name 百强蓝润 is just to emphasize they are being on top 100

Comment: and that's the top 100 of what?

Answer (score 1):

百强企业 means top 100 enterprises.

Comment: In what context? Revenue? Worth? Customer Service?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure just like in English it means top 100 of ANY list.

For example, Lanrun is top 100 in the housing industry in China: http://house.baidu.com/sc/scan/0/5986738501256011448/

Comment: Sure, but isn't going around calling yourself 百强蓝润, as opposed to 房地产前百强蓝润, a little bit ambiguous, let alone misleading?

Comment: I mean lots of stores everywhere do this... Like for example, Best Buy implicitly states that they are the best, which is misleading/advertisement at best.

Answer (score 0):

(#)强 means top (#) of any possible kind of list.

But apparently 五百强 became an expression to also express Fortune Five Hundred.